# Resuming Camel Processing after power failure

Tags: apache-camel, shiro, terracotta

I'm currently developing a Camel Integration app in which resumption from a previous state of processing is important. When there's a power outage, for instance, it's important that all previously processed messages are not re-processed. The processing should resume from where it left off before the outage.

I've gone through a number of possible solutions including Terracotta and [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/). I'm not sure how to use either as documentation on the integration with Apache Camel is scarce. I've not settled on the two, however.

I'm looking for suggestions on the potential alternatives I can use or a pointer to some tutorial to get me started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty in surviving outages lies primarily in state, and what to do with in-flight messages.

Usually, when you're talking state within routes the solution is to flush it to disk, or other nodes in the cluster. Taking the aggregator pattern as an example, aggregated state is persisted in an aggregation repository. The default implementation is in memory, so if the power goes out, all the state is lost. However, there are other implementations, including one for JDBC, and another using Hazelcast (a lightweight in-memory data grid). I haven't used Hazelcast myself, but JDBC does a synchronous write to disk. The aggregator pattern allows you to resume from where you left off. A similar solution exists for idempotent consumption.

The second question, around in-flight messages is a little more complicated, and largely depends on where you are consuming from. If you're in the middle of handling a web service request, and the power goes out, does it matter if you have lost the message? The user can simply retry. Any effects on external systems can be wrapped in a transaction, or an idempotent consumer with JDBC idempotent repository.

If you are building out integrations based on messaging, you should consume within a transaction, so that if your server goes down, the messages go back into the broker and can be replayed to another consumer.

Be careful when using `seda:` or `threads` blocks, these use an in-memory queue to pass exchanges between threads, any messages flowing down these sorts of routes will be lost if someone trips over the power cable. If you can't afford message loss, and need this sort of processing model, consider using a JMS queue as the endpoints between the two routes (with transactions to ensure you pick up where you left off).

Comment: This is very helpful advice, @Jake. I'll do more research based on your suggestion.